# Is there a general solution to this phase-shifted system of equations?

Tags: recurrence-relations, systems-of-equations

This is a (more general) question related to "[Estimated solution to system of equations with phase-shifted functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1088934/estimated-solution-to-system-of-equations-with-phase-shifted-functions)".

Given this system of two equations and two unknown functions:

$$ y_1(t) = \mu_{1a} f_a(t-\phi_{1a}) + \mu_{1b} f_b(t-\phi_{1b})  $$
$$ y_2(t) = \mu_{2a} f_a(t-\phi_{2a}) + \mu_{2b} f_b(t-\phi_{2b})  $$

A solution (I think) is:

$$
f_a(t) - \frac { \mu_{1b} \mu_{2a} } { \mu_{1a} \mu_{2b} } f_a
\left(t + \phi_{1a} - \phi_{1b} - \phi_{2a} + \phi_{2b} \right) =
\frac 1 {\mu_{1a}}
\left[
y_1 \left( t + \phi_{1a} \right)
- \frac {\mu_{1b}} {\mu_{2b}}
y_2 \left( t + \phi_{1a} - \phi_{1b} + \phi_{2b} \right)
\right]
$$

The solution to the recurrence relation:

$$
f_a(t) = \frac 1 {\mu_{1a}} \sum_{i=0}^\infty
\left( \frac { \mu_{1b} \mu_{2a} } { \mu_{1a} \mu_{2b} } \right)^i
\left[
y_1 \left( t + \phi_{1a} + i \left( \phi_{1a} - \phi_{1b} - \phi_{2a} + \phi_{2b} \right) \right)
- \frac {\mu_{1b}} {\mu_{2b}}
y_2 \left( t + \phi_{1a} - \phi_{1b} + \phi_{2b} +
i \left( \phi_{1a} - \phi_{1b} - \phi_{2a} + \phi_{2b} \right) \right)
\right]
$$

This is based on the fact (?) that, given some original $f(t)$ and $g(t) = f(t) + \mu f(t-\phi)$, the original can be restored via

$$f(t) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty (-\mu)^i g(t-\phi i)$$

- Is the above correct?
- How do I generalize this process for a large number of similar equations?

Comment: How did you find your proposed solution to that recurrence relation?

Comment: Added what I think is the generic recurrence solution.

Comment: Interesting, I think that solution is formally correct. However, do you know if $|\mu|$ is small (ie. less than $1$?) If not, then there's a problem. In practice, you obviously have to truncate that infinite series at $N$ terms. By substituting your formula into the recurrence relation, something like $\mu^{N+1}g[t - (N + 1)\phi]$ gets left over so if $\mu$ isn't small, this term won't be small and the series may not converge to $f(t)$.

Comment: You make a good point about convergence. If $|\mu| > 1$ then simply divide the previous equation by $\mu$, add $\phi$ to both function arguments and you will have a new equation for which $|\mu| < 1$.

Comment: Okay, I think we're getting somewhere. You said in the original question that there might be more degrees of freedom than equations, so in this case I take that to mean that there might be more $f$s than $y$s. Suppose that there are $3$ $f$s and $2$ $y$s, then you could, for example solve for $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ in terms of $y_{1}, y_{2}$ and $f_{3}$, but then $f_{3}$ is arbitrary and there's no way to "solve for it" from a linear algebra perspective. Are there any other constraints?

Comment: For this question we can assume that the system is not underdetermined and that the number of equations matches the number of unknowns.

Comment: Okay cool, I think that's enough information to convince me that the general solution is possible. I'll have to think of a way to write it that looks reasonable though (if no one else does, of course.)

Comment: I may have spoken too soon. After trying some higher-order cases it doesn't look like the recurrence relations are solvable analytically. To be honest, I'm not really familiar with numerically solving systems of recurrence relations, although I think in many ways they're similar to differential equations. I'll think about it a bit more.